# server prematurely closed connection

Tags: http, webserver, load-testing, performance-testing, connection

I have been performing load testing on a server to test if it can handle the expected number of users that will access a web app deployed on it.  While performing load testing, I noticed that for about 5% of simulated users, the server at least once prematurely closed the http connection.  However, I also noticed that during those times, CPU utilization and memory usage was really low. My question is why would the server be dropping connections if it has the memory and CPU to address them.

Comment: which server (incl. version) are you using? Do you use http, or https?